# How to proxy multipart request in springboot

Tags: spring, spring-boot, reverse-proxy

I have below method in my proxy controller which I am trying to proxy to downstream service.

```java
    @PostMapping(value = "/**",
            consumes = [MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE],
            produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    ResponseEntity proxyPostRequest(@RequestHeader HttpHeaders requestHeaders, HttpServletRequest request, ProxyExchange<String> proxy) throws Exception {
        requestHeaders.addIfAbsent("x-program-id", request.getAttribute("programId").toString())
        // required for host header match
        requestHeaders.remove(HttpHeaders.HOST)
        requestHeaders.add(HttpHeaders.HOST, host)
        proxy.headers(requestHeaders)
        final URI uri = new URI(scheme, null, host, Integer.valueOf(port), request.getRequestURI(), request.getQueryString(), null)
        ResponseEntity responseEntity = proxy.uri(uri).post()
        return enrichResponse(responseEntity)
    }
```

I am getting below error in downstream service:

```
Could not resolve parameter [0] in public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity
```

But upon hitting the same API in downstream service directly, it is working fine.

Seems I am doing something wrong in reverse-proxying the request.
Below is the sample cURL request I am trying:

```
curl --location 'http://localhost:8080/test/path/'\
--form 'logoFile=@"path-to-file.txt"' \
--form 'message="hello"'
```